# Java RegEx getting tail after matching as String

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if there is a way to get the tail after matching in `java.util.regex.Matcher` as String not appending it to a StringBuffer, which is what Matcher.`appendTail(StringBuffer)` does. I know that I can just create a StringBuffer and append that one String to it and convert it to a String but I was wondering if there is a more direct way.

```
StringBuffer tailBfr = new StringBuffer();              
mtchr.appendTail(tailBfr);
String tail = tailBfr.toString();
```

Since there is no String getTail() method.

I tried getting the group count and then iterating through groups to see if it may be stored in one of them but it wasn't.

Thanks

Comment: You are absolutely not clarifying your problem. An example would help us understand what you want.

Comment: I want something like String tail = Matcher.getTail();  instead of streaming that tail into a StringBuffer

Answer (score 1):

If you append

```
(.*)\\Z
```

to the regex pattern, you will get the tail of the text as the last capture group